# Is it possible to override a class' __call__ method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to change the behavior of the `__call__` method of a given object. The naive approach would be something like:

```
class A(object):
    def __call__(self):
        return 1

def new_call():
    return 42


a = A()
a.__call__ = new_call
```

Why is it not the output of `a()` 42? Is there a workaround I can exploit to achieve the same effect? (without using the class)

---

============================    EDIT =================================

For the records, the short answer is no. Python calls the "special methods" like `__call_` directly on the class and not on the instance, therefore if you need to change the method, you need to change it on the class itself.

Comment: First don’t you need to include the self argument in new_call? And why not just subclass the A class

Answer (score 5):

Special methods (aka "dunder" methods) are looked-up with respect to the *class* of the object, so to override it you would need to change the class, not the instance. Also note that methods all have an initial argument passed to them, usually called `self`.

The following would do what you want (notice how that it affects *all* instances of the class):

```
class A(object):
    def __call__(self):
        return 1

def new_call(self):
    return 42


a1 = A()
a2 = A()
A.__call__ = new_call

print(a1())  # -> 42
print(a2())  # -> 42
```

If you only want to change a specific instance, a relatively simple workaround is to make the class' `__call_()` method call one that's *not* "special" like it is — i.e. by introducing a level of indirection.

Here's what I mean:

```
# Workaround

class B(object):
    def __call__(self):
        return self.call_method(self)

    @staticmethod
    def call_method(self):
        return 1

def new_call(self):
    return 42

# Create two instances for testing.
b1 = B()
b2 = B()
b2.call_method = new_call  # Will only affect this instance.

print(b1())  # -> 1
print(b2())  # -> 42
```

Answer (score 4):

Typically, special method names, such as `__call__`, are accessed via the object's type, rather than the instance's attribute collection. From [Special Method Names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names):

> If a class defines a method named `__getitem__()`, and x is an instance of this class, then `x[i]` is roughly equivalent to `type(x).__getitem__(x, i)`.

This also applies to `__call__`. `a()` is roughly equivalent to `type(a).__call__(a)`. Changing `a`'s `__call__` attribute doesn't have an effect, because the code is looking for A's `__call__` attribute.

Assigning a new function to `A.__call__` should do what you want.

```
class A(object):
    def __call__(self):
        return 1

def new_call(self):
    return 42


a = A()
A.__call__ = new_call
print(a())
```

Result:

```
42
```

Comment: This changes `__call__` for *all* instances of `A`, though, not just `a`, which I think is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Exactly, this way I cannot change two different objects is a different way. Nevertheless thanks for the valuable explanation

Comment: Hmm, tricky. AFAICT, special method lookup doesn't bother to look at the instance's attributes, even if the class doesn't define the method. So it's hard to get per-instance behavior. Jordan Brière's approach, or something like it, is probably the simplest way to explicitly "dispatch" the behavior of `__call__` to each instance.

Answer (score 0):

Because `A.__call__` is resolved before `a.__call__`. If you want to bind `__call__` per instance, then you have to change the resolution by attempting to resolve it from there. E.g.

```
class A(object):
    def __call__(self):
        try:
            return vars(self)['__call__']()
        except KeyError:
            return 1

def new_call():
    return 42


a = A()

print(a())
a.__call__ = new_call
print(a())
```

Would prints:

```
1
42
```

If you want it to be a method, and have access to `self`, then you have to bind it. E.g.

```
from types import MethodType

class A(object):
    def __call__(self):
        try:
            return vars(self)['__call__']()
        except KeyError:
            return 1

def new_call_method(self):
    return self

a = A()
a.__call__ = MethodType(new_call_method, a)
also_a = a()
```

Would return `a`.

Comment: Don't use a bare `except`. The only exception you should be catching is the `KeyError` when the instance variable `__call__` isn't present. That implies that you should call `vars` before the `try` statement, and only attempt to call the result of `whatever['__call__']` after the `try` statement.

Comment: I'm lost here, `a()` still returns `1`, isn't it?

Comment: No, `a()` returns `42`, because `a.__dict__` is looked first into `A.__call__` and fallback to returning `1`.

Comment: The second attempt fails because magic methods go directly to the class attribute, not an instance attribute.

Comment: The second attempt relies on the first `A` definition. I didn't re-define it, to avoid duplicating the code.

Comment: No, the point is that `a(...)` is *always* `A.__call__(a, ...)`, whether or not `a.__call__` is defined.

Comment: I tend to agree with @chepner, can you post a full code snippet, maybe I'm missing something

Comment: It is, hence why `A.__call__` first tries to `return vars(self)['__call__']()`, which will resolve from the instance `a.__call__`, or fallback to `return 1`.

Comment: Edited the second snippet, by adding the class definition from the first one. The second was really just an extra, showing how to bind the instance so that it passes `self` to the new call method.

Comment: @JordanBrière You have two completely different solutions here: the first one works, because you generalized `A.__call__`. The second one does not, because you can't "preempt" `A.__call__` by defining `a.__call__`. That simply isn't how the `()` call syntax works.

Comment: Ok, now I got what you meant. Still, I wish I was not forced to change the class definition